# Find an $x$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(x) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find an $x$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(x) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$.

For my abstract algebra class. Don't really know where to start, or how to finish for that matter.

Comment: Have you seen a constructive proof for the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)?

Comment: We can't answer this question without a lot more information. You need to know what the function $Q$ does, what its domain is, and its codomain. Please read the context around your question, post as much as you can find, and maybe explain your initial thoughts on how to start.

Comment: Since this is tagged abstract-algebra, I think this is about extending $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is QQ . I hadn't thought to use the primitive element theorem. Though I still don't understand how I find c.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know a good way of finding $c$ either, other than just trying random small integers. Once you pick $c$, try to generate all three of your original generators (that's just linear algebra), and if you can't, try again.

Comment: There have been other questions about this special sort of extension, e.g., to show that it is the obviously-plausible $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})$, with various levels of decisive proofs of this and variously-more-general analogous assertions.

Answer (score 1):

First consider $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$, that element has minimum polynomial $x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$ and you can recover $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ from it and it's conjugates.

This hints the next one might be $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3 + \sqrt 5$, why not try it out and see if it works?

Comment: I don't see how Q(sqrt(2) + sqrt(3)) returns x^4 - 10x^2 +1.